# Is there a way to develop offline chat app in flutter and dart by establishing connection between routers?

Tags: flutter, dart, router, offlineapps

I am trying to find a way to develop an offline chat app by establishing a connection between two routers in a flutter.

I searched a lot and couldn't find a concrete answer. There will be a connection between two routers and the users connected to the router can chat offline send and receive messages, share videos, and files.

Comment: The word "router" is overloaded.  Do you mean a route handler within your app, or do you mean a literal network router?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use same connection between devices.

i found the github repository for offline chat :

https://github.com/loonix/flutter-offline-chat